# Creating point with geometry to insert in database

Tags: postgis, postgresql, php

I have a PostGIS table of points. With my php code and pdo, I want to add a point in it. I have the coordinates, I want to get the geometry, with ST_GeomFromText. Here is the code :

```
$x = $_POST['x'];
$y = $_POST['y'];
$geom="ST_GeomFromText('POINT($x $y)',2154)";
$r = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO ouvragesp (id, yl93, xl93,annee,geom) VALUES(:identifiant , :y , :x , 2017, :geom)");
$r->execute(array(
  'identifiant' => $id,
  'x' => $x,
  'y' => $y,
  'geom' => $geom));
```

However, when I execute it, it tells me that :

```
PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[XX000]: Internal error: 7 ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry HINT: "ST" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
```

I don't see why it takes only "ST" part.

Does someone know where the problem comes from and how to solve it ?

Comment: did you try to escape the underscore?

Comment: Sounds more like a PHP problem.

Comment: @Mazu_R yes I tried to escape it, nothing change. The problem does not come from that : whatever the word, it takes only the 2 first letters

Comment: @bugmenot123 Perhaps I should better post it on stackoverflow ?

Comment: I would as well try on stackoverflow as it seems to be PHP specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to this post : [pdo prepare statement with functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963129/postgisl-pdo-prepare-insert-functions-quoted)

It is more a php question as bugmenot123 pointed out, but just in case I post the solution anyway :)

The trick was to put the function in the prepare part but the creation of the point in the execute part.

```
$r = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO ouvragesp (id, yl93, xl93,annee,geom) VALUES(:identifiant , :y , :x , 2017,ST_GeomFromText(:geom,2154))");
  $r->execute(array(
  'identifiant' => $id,
  'x' => $x,
  'y' => $y,
  'geom' => "POINT($x $y)"));
```